# Search by whitespace-delimited query string across differend fields

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Here's my example set of indexed entities. Let's say it represents set of Product orders by Customers.

```
[
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "Product": "Peugeot",
        "Customer": "John Woo"
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "Product": "Peugeot",
        "Customer": "John Carpenter"
    },
    {
        "Id": 3,
        "Product": "Peugeot",
        "Customer": "Bruce Lee"
    },
]
```

Please note that all of them are 'Peugeot', but the Customers are different: there are two 'Johns' and one 'Bruce Lee'.

Here's my query string:
'`Peugeot John`'

What I want from Elastic is to return all 'Peugeot' products ordered by customers with 'John' in their names. Which means this result:

```
[
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "Product": "Peugeot",
        "Customer": "John Woo"
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "Product": "Peugeot",
        "Customer": "John Carpenter"
    }
]
```

Please note that entity with Id=3 should be skipped because the customer is 'Bruce Lee'. So each word in query string should be applied to the whole object, not to every field sequentially.

So I run my "multi_match" query using NEST C# library:

```
elasticClient.SearchAsync<OrderModel>(descriptor => 
    descriptor
        .Index("myIndex")
        .Size(20)
        .Query(q => q
            .MultiMatch(m => m
                .Fields(f => f
                    .Fields(
                        p => p.Product,
                        p => p.Customer
                    )
                )
                .Operator(Operator.And)
                .Query("Peugeot John")
            )
        )
)
```

It returns nothing. Because it splits the query into two words: 'Peugeot' and 'John' and applies them to each field using AND operator. Since there are no fields with values which contain 'Peugeot' and 'John' together the result is empty.

When I change operator to OR the behaviour is still incorrect: it returns all 3 objects because all of them match 'Peugeot' word.

So how can I achieve the sort of 'object-wide-delimited-query-exclusive-search' behaviour?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like good fit for [cross_field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#type-cross-fields) type of [multi-match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#query-dsl-multi-match-query)

```
var results = await client.SearchAsync<Document>(s => s
    .Query(q => q.MultiMatch(m => m
        .Fields(f => f.Fields("product", "customer"))
        .Type(TextQueryType.CrossFields)
        .Operator(Operator.And)
        .Query(query))));
```

Output:

```
Results for query "Peugeot John":
Peugeot - John Woo
Peugeot - John Carpenter
```

Comment: Thanks Rob. Works perfectly, just what I needed.